# Bypass VPN with VS Code Live Share - Security Risk?

Tags: windows-10, vpn, visual-studio-code

If I:

1. log into a remote Windows 10 Computer with Windows Remote Desktop over a VPN,
2. start VS Code,
3. share the VS Code session with the Live Share extension,
4. share a VS Code terminal with read/write access,
5. send the VS Code Live Share session link to myself,
6. disconnect from the remote Windows 10 desktop session,
7. disconnect from the VPN,
8. follow the VS Code Live Share link I sent to myself, which opens the shared VS Code session running on the Remote Windows 10 computer.

I can now run code and have full access to the network through the shared terminal without going through a VPN.

What are the specific security risks when doing this?

Comment: "Is there any security risk doing this?" - Yes;

Comment: Yes, I suppose that is always the case. clarified my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the article
[Security features of Live Share](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/reference/security).
It seems like Microsoft did give some thought to the subject:

- Secure connectivity
  All connections in Visual Studio Live Share are SSH or SSL encrypted and authenticated against a central service to ensure that only those in the collaboration session can gain access to its content.
- Invitations and join access
  Each time you start a new collaboration session, Live Share generates a new unique identifier that is placed in the invitation link.
- Unexpected guest
  You are automatically notified whenever a guest joins the session
  and can remove him.
- Requiring guest approval
  You may lock a session with multiple available options.

Read the article for more details and more security options.

Comment: to ssh into this computer or any other computer from outside the network, I have to be logged into the VPN.  When going through the Live Share extension, I no longer need to be logged into the VPN to access the network.  However, I still need to validate my credentials through our corporate Office 365 sign-in page.